# Does Office 365 image search work? If so, how?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

According to Microsoft ("Image Analysis" in https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-SharePoint-Blog/Enrich-your-SharePoint-Content-with-Intelligence-and-Automation/ba-p/194174, from May 21, 2018), we should be able to search for text within images.

Is this working for you/anyone? If so, I would like to know what you had to do to get it to work.

I have a SharePoint modern team site with PNG images that contain clearly readable text...but search will not find anything. I have requested re-indexing.

I have had a Microsoft Support request (#10638094) open since June 27 with this question/issue, and no one--even after escalation--has been able to answer it.

Based on the article above, it appears that "MediaService" column(s) should be added to the library to support this; however, I can find no such columns in the environment (using PnP export to review).

Naomi Moneypenny and Kathrine Hammervold highlighted this functionality at Ignite 2017 (https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/Microsoft-Ignite-Orlando-2017/BRK2181, about 27:00), but it doesn't seem to be available/working (at least not for me).

**August 24**:  So, after research, digging yet further, I have an escalated support ticket at Microsoft (#10638094, unsolved) and there are conversations at https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Intelligent-Search-Discovery/Search-for-words-in-your-images-in-Office-365/ba-p/135703, https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-SharePoint-Blog/Enrich-your-SharePoint-Content-with-Intelligence-and-Automation/bc-p/236625, and [Does Office 365 image search work? If so, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51934105/does-office-365-image-search-work-if-so-how/51999323#51999323).  I have yet to hear of this functionality working for anyone.  I will keep digging, and I will certainly post if I hear anything.  J

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, from official it seems already released at the end of 2017. However there is no any related doc or official guide to this Text in image search function.

The 2 way i can think of perform text in image search.

1. Perform OCR yourself on the image before uploading the image and embed the text in image metadata.
2. Use support image type like IIRC and TIF that image are recognized.

In your case, you can upload the image and have another column that contains text and apply metadata to the image in a list/ library column.

OneDrive in another hand also has this function. For example, search for things like "cat" and it * should* pull up most pictures you have of cats. Its more likely using tag as label for the image instead of reading the picture it self.

Also, i believe OneNote has its index recognizable text and handwriting. Maybe this can point you to the right directions.

*Microsoft Azure's computer Vision offer service to recognized text in image. Maybe [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/) can help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. May dig further into these if image search never works.  J

Answer (score 0):

"Is this working for you/anyone?"  Yes, I responded to this post elsewhere and see it posted here, as well.  Unfortunately, I cannot tell you HOW to get it to work or to verify that it is correctly configured.  I can only suggest a test for you to see if it is working for you, as it works for me.  I have not tested every way in which it could or should work.  I have only discovered it working with PNGs I inserted into Wiki Pages in SharePoint Online.  Those PNGs are generated using Snag-It to take Screen Captures and I do not see where Snag-It would be doing any OCR on the image to embed anything, etc.  OCR is not even in the Snag-It help file, so I believe the PNG files are just simple PNGs.  I insert them into the SharePoint Wiki page, which uploads them to the Site Assets library.  And, when I search for a word in the image, the image is returned as a result - not the Wiki page.  So, suggest you try a simple test of just inserting a PNG with text in it into a Wiki Page and give the index a bit of time to run to see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the functionality has matured recently.  I have been testing it more thoroughly, and I have documented the results in my blog at http://www.collaboration-foundry.com/SharePointImageAnalysis.

**Bottom line**: It works for me in OneDrive and SharePoint (modern and classis), but I've only seen it work on the out-of-the-box Document content type--which limits custom solutions somewhat.

It's cool functionality when it works.  Looking forward to seeing Microsoft build on this.
John